According to Eastern Orthodoxy does God have a soul?
The question is:  According to Eastern Orthodoxy, does God have a soul?
Understandably, the answer will have to incorporate the EO definition of 'soul' and, if yes, whether it differs from the 'human soul'.
Related: What does Lutheranism say about God's soul?, A question for Roman Catholicism about the soul of God?, What is the Methodist position on God's soul?, Do Baptists say God has a soul?, Does God have a soul according to Presbyterians?, Do Anglicans think God has a soul?, Do Pentecostals teach that God has a soul?

From the perspective of the scriptures and traditions of the Orthodox church including the words and writings of the blessed forefathers I will do my best to give this perspective.

What is a soul?

Saint John the Damascan: ‘The soul, therefore, is a living essence, uncomplicated, incorporeal, invisible – in its proper nature – to the eyes of the body, immortal, reasoning and intelligent, formless, making use of an organic body and being the source of its powers of life, growth, sensation and generation, the intellect being its purest part though not in any way alien to it (as the eye is to the body, so the intellect is to the soul). It has power over itself, its volition and energy, and is mutable, i.e. able to be changed, because it is created. All of these features are natural to it through the Grace imparted by its Creator, and it's being and nature are thus because of this same Grace which it has received’.


What is an essence? When we say ‘essence’, in Christian ontology (as in Aristotelian), we mean a thing which exists in itself, not dependent on something else for its existence. The soul is, indeed, firmly linked to the body, but it is to be distinguished from it. Every essence, whether created or uncreated, has its own energy, which is peculiar to it.

These two things allow us to already answer the question. God is uncreated. God however does have "an essence"
Answer: No, God does not have a Soul
Nuanced answer: Well... Jesus does. Jesus is fully divine and Jesus is fully human, Body, Spirit and Soul. So "technically" there is a yes there, within the person of Christ in the Trinity.

If you want to ask about how Eastern Orthodoxy considers the essence of The Divine and that of humans to be different... that's a different question.

Thank you. And what does Eastern orthodoxy do with the few passages which seem to state that God does have a soul? For example Judges 10:16 and Hebrews 10:38?

@ Wyrsa To be honest with you, I don't think that Jesus has a soul. He did have it but poured it out to atone for the humanity. As Leviticus 17:11 says, the soul of the flesh is in the blood. Resurrected Jesus is like Adam in the garden. Flesh and bones (Genesis 2:23, Luke 24:39). Resurrected Christ is what Adam was going to become, though. Jesus' wounds did not bleed after the resurrection. And the blood appears for the first time after the fall, in the Cain and Abel story. Christ's body is not animated by the blood, which is closely connected to the soul, any more.

It is transformed and animated by God's Spirit that He can share with us, the believers. Through His Spirit, we are adopted as the sons and daughters of God. Hebrews 2:14 says that Jesus became flesh and blood to become mortal and defeat the devil through His death. He became what we are to make us what He is.

@ארקדיוס   Wyrsa is explaining the teachings of Orthodox. "I don't think that Jesus has a soul" - this isn't about what you think.

@ארקדיוס That is an interesting perspective, but you say "like Adam" where I would say "better than Adam" and some other things in the middle, but at the end you have the right statement. "The incarnation transformed us fundamentally to allow us to be more like God" Which we had lost in the fall. For the Orthodox perspective of that, look at "Theosis" as Salvation. :)

@MikeBorden You forgot leviticus 26:11 and Jeremiah 32:41... but these are similar to the verses that say "God's" face" or "God's hands". Specifically no where in the Bible does it say specifically that God has a soul, God is Spirit specifically from John 4:24. But it depends on how you speak of "soul", some people think of "personhood" or "having a soul" like having emotions. God has both of those things, but we have no revelation from God that says that He has a Soul. We have revelation through scripture that God is Spirit. The fact that Jesus has a soul is likely important, Hebrews 7:25.

@Wyrsa Yes, Jesus is better than Adam after creation. First man was an unfinished project, so to speak. His nakedness being the indication of that reality. Ancient rabbis noticed that the pronunciation of the tunics of skins that Adam and Eve wore after the fall, is the same as tunics of light. Interesting play of words. It makes one think about the clothes of Jesus that became bright as light during His transfiguration. 
I read about theosis. It helped me to tie some loose threads. I have been learning a lot from the orthodox theology.

In Orthodox anthropology, I've generally heard it expressed that man is a soul and has a body.

I would think the answer is "no", the same answer by Catholics and Protestants.  None of the 3 main branches use the term "soul" to talk about God's (divine) nature.
Instead we all say God IS "spirit", rather than say God has a "soul".  The term "soul" seems to be reserved for the animating agent of the human body (or even an animal or a plant).  When God the Word takes on flesh, the Word adds on a human nature, at which point the human soul (along with its body) was created in the womb of Virgin Mary.
Maybe prior to Chalcedon there was the use of the term "soul" when talking about God's nature (although unlikely), but since Chalcedon I would think the theological terms used to describe the Trinitarian God would have been more precise.  The term "Trinitarian life" or the "immanent life" seems to be the preferred terminology rather than divine "soul".
From another angle, even if we want to posit a definition for divine "soul" and then say God has a (divine) "soul" this could run afoul of divine simplicity because this could imply that God is a composite.  Or worse, God is subsumed under a genus (a category for those who have this divine "soul"). But our God is a truly unique Being, there is none other.  We use "IS" instead of "has a" when discussing God's nature to reflect His uniqueness and His simplicity. Rather, we talk about the divine "nature" that is shared by all 3 "persons" of the Trinity, "person" being a conceptual picture of something truly Real but yet doesn't divide this unique Being of God.
You may ask, why not call "nature" by the term "(divine) soul"?  Maybe it's an accident of history, or maybe the term "nature" already has connotations that are more readily applicable to Patristic talk about God.  Or maybe because the term "soul" has, since Aristotle, been used in association with a body, this term is not considered at all when talking about the Christian God who (apart from the Incarnation) doesn't have a body.

For support that the above conceptual analysis is consistent with the teaching of the Eastern Orthodox church, please refer to Orthodox Church in America's The Orthodox Faith series.  In the relevant sections on the

One Divine Nature and Being of God and
The Three Divine Persons

we don't see any use of the term "soul".  If Eastern Orthodox teaches that God has a soul, we should have seen the term used in those pages, if not seeing the definition of (divine) "soul" as well.  But I couldn't find any Eastern Orthodox literature that does that.

The Bible uses soul for animals as well.. just not a soul that lives for ever.  Perhaps change that bit of answer?  To me, soul is spirit which is designed to be joined to a physical body, human or animal. And soul is used of the real me.. I am a soul.  And I can lose my own soul, meaning I can lose my self in an everlasting loss... my soul is lost to what could have been.. everlasting well-being.

@AndrewShanks Modern Thomism defines soul similarly, that it is not an entity that lives forever unless God wants to sustain it.  About animal / plant "soul", it is an Aristotelian principle as well, as the animating principle.  In this answer I only address potential complication when any of those conceptual elements are used for God, so I only include definition pertaining to the human nature.
